# Formulário Jquery + Angular não passam um valor de input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, angularjs

Estou fazendo um post com Angular. Ele funciona normal quando digito manualmente os valores no formulário, porém ele recebe um valor via jQuery `$("#id_veiculo").val(valores02.id);` e este valor aparece corretamente, mas na hora de enviar o valor deste input acaba sumindo.

Segue código:
http://pastebin.com/jJ4k2TkT

```
<form class="form-inline" ng-controller="FormController" ng-submit="submitForm()" role="form" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_veiculo" ng-model="id_veiculo" value="">  <!-- Esta input só funciona quando digito manualmente o valor, ela recebe por jquery mas na hora de enviar se torna vazia ou nula -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only">Itens Opcionais:</label>

        <?php
        echo ' <select ng-model="id_opcional">';

        foreach ($opcionais_encontrados as $o):
            echo '<option value="' . $o->id . '">' . $o->opcional . '</option>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</select>';
        ?>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Submit Record</button>
    <pre style="display:none;">{{ message}}</pre>
</form>
```

o app.js

```
'use strict';

(function(){
var HC = {};
var App = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var $scope;

HC.FormController = function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.id_veiculo = undefined;
    $scope.id_opcional = undefined;
    $scope.message = undefined;

    $scope.submitForm = function() {        
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://cipauto/painel/opcionais/add',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" :  "application/json"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({id_veiculo: $scope.id_veiculo, id_opcional: $scope.id_opcional})
        }).success(function(data){                              
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("table")).scope();
            scope.rows.push({id_veiculo: $scope.id_veiculo, id_opcional: $scope.id_opcional});
            $scope.rows = scope;
            //alertify.notify(data.message, data.status, 5, function() { console.log(data.message); });
        });
    }
};


HC.TableViewController = function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://cipauto/painel/opcionais/listAll',
        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.rows = data;
    });
};

App.controller('TableViewController', HC.TableViewController);
App.controller('FormController', HC.FormController);

return HC;

})();
```

Pelo que percebi o problema deve estar no `$scope.id_veiculo = undefined;`.
Como faço para adicionar o valor da input `#id_seminovo` que é atribuído pelo jQuery citado acima.

Comment: Marque a pergunta como resolvida =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o próprio angular para definir o valor do campo id_veiculo.

```
//recupera o scopo do angular
var scope = angular.element('[ng-controller=FormController]').scope();
//define o valor
scope.test2 = 'id_veiculo';
//faz o apply no scope para poder atualizar o valor definido acima na pagina, ou seja, fazer o bind
scope.$apply();
```

[Exemplo bem explicativo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9NxOFeLs0oVSJ1ejALEj?p=preview)

Lembrando que essa forma não é tão utilizada, mas quebra um galho para o que você quer. O ideal era entender melhor como é o funcionamento da sua aplicação para tentar tratar isso diretamente no controller, por exemplo.